# The HTML code is not formatted on frontend page

Tags: html

I am not 100% sure if I am using the correct term for my issue. I wondering why it is showing the elements on our website browser (See Image Example).

[image: HTML CODE in our Website Description]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That indicates the content of Specifications showing raw, and does not format HTML code.

There are 2 cases:

1. Your field (Specifications) has an issue, it does not format HTML code.
2. You edit the content the wrong way.

If you paste your content with HTML code, it should go to **Hide Editor** mode:
[image]
It should not go to **Show Editor** mode:
[image]

Comment: If this answer works as your expected, please mark it as **accepted**. That indicates your issue is solved and makes it easier for others with the same issue to find a verified answer.

Comment: Understood. Thank you!

Comment: I'm glad to help.